# using built-in pandas groupby metrics drawn from a list of said metrics

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe for which I have to calculate a series of metrics grouped by certain columns in the dataframe. I'd like to do this using a loop, but I cannot seem to figure out how (if there is a correct way).

So, what I'm trying to do is basically (semi-pseudo code, this does not run for obvious reasons):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A'],
                   'Score': range(7)})

group = df.groupby('ID')
for stat in ['mean', 'min', 'max']:
    group.stat()
```

I can get this to work if I use `numpy` and `getattr`. I.E.:

```
for stat in ['mean', 'min', 'max']:
    df.groupby('ID').apply(getattr(np, stat))
```

The problem with this is that it is significantly slower than using the built-in `.mean()`, etc. pandas provides (at least for the size dataframe that I'm working with).

Is there a more appropriate way to accomplish this?

Comment: You should only group your data once. Once grouped, you can apply multiple aggregations (sum, min, max, etc).

Comment: right, that was my error with making the toy example - I have the groupby outside of my loop in my actual use case. MaxU's answer suggests using agg, but this leads to a bit more of a complicated result (as I indicate in the comment below his answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [116]: stats = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(['mean','min','max'])

In [117]: stats
Out[117]:
       Score
        mean min max
ID
A   2.666667   0   6
B   2.500000   1   4
C   4.000000   3   5

In [118]: stats.columns = ['{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format(tup) for tup in stats.columns]

In [119]: stats
Out[119]:
    mean_Score  min_Score  max_Score
ID
A     2.666667          0          6
B     2.500000          1          4
C     4.000000          3          5

In [120]: stats.reset_index()
Out[120]:
  ID  mean_Score  min_Score  max_Score
0  A    2.666667          0          6
1  B    2.500000          1          4
2  C    4.000000          3          5
```

**old answer:**

```
In [51]: df.groupby('ID').agg(['mean','min','max'])
Out[51]:
       Score
        mean min max
ID
A   2.666667   0   6
B   2.500000   1   4
C   4.000000   3   5
```

Comment: I'm aware of `agg`, and I suppose I could do it this way. The actual use case, though, is calculating these metrics on a series of columns, renaming those columns, and adding those new columns with the label for each metric appended to the column name back in to the dataframe (the groupby is really on a series of datetimes). I was trying to avoid looping over all of the columns, which using `agg` would require met to do to ultimately generate the desired result

Comment: @user3014097, do you want to apply those aggregation functions on different columns or on the same one?

Comment: Same columns, but with `agg` I end up with subsets of columns. So, if I have columns A, B I end up with `df.A.mean`, `df.A.min`, etc - which I don't want. Rather, I need columns `[mean_A, min_A, etc]`. To get that, using `agg`, I have to loop over and generate those columns individually, as far as i can tell. Which works fine if there's no way to do it how I suggested in the OP, it's just less succinct.

Comment: @user3014097, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom grouping function that takes a dataframe, a list of columns on which you'd like to group, a list of columns you'd like to aggregate, and a list of functions to apply to those columns:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Sample data.
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
df['labels'] = ['a'] * 3 + ['b'] * 2
>>> df
          A         B         C labels
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738      a
1  2.240893  1.867558 -0.977278      a
2  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219      a
3  0.410599  0.144044  1.454274      b
4  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863      b

# Custom function.
def group_agg(df, groupby, columns=None, funcs=None):
    if not funcs:
        funcs = sum
    if not columns:
        columns = df.columns
    gb = df.groupby(groupby)
    dfs = []
    func_names = [re.findall(r'>?function (\w*)', str(foo))[0] for foo in funcs]
    for col in columns:
        col_names = (col + "_" + name for name in func_names)
        names_func_dict = {col_name: foo for col_name, foo in zip(col_names, funcs)}
        dfs.append(gb[col].agg(names_func_dict))
    return pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

# Example result.
>>> group_agg(df, groupby=['labels'], funcs=[sum, np.mean], columns=['A', 'B'])
           A_sum    A_mean    B_mean     B_sum
labels                                        
a       4.955034  1.651678  0.705453  2.116358
b       1.171636  0.585818  0.132859  0.265719
```

There is a regex statement to get the function names.

```
>>> [str(foo) for foo in funcs]
['<built-in function sum>', '<function mean at 0x108f86ed8>']

>>> [re.findall(r'>?function (\w*)', str(foo))[0] for foo in funcs]
['sum', 'mean']
```

These names are then joined to the column, a a dictionary comprehension maps these names to the function.

For column `A`, for example, this is the contents of `names_func_dict`:

```
{'A_mean': <function numpy.core.fromnumeric.mean>, 
 'A_sum': <function sum>}
```

This dictionary is then passed to the `groupby[coll].agg()` function.